# The exam is marked out of 50

Tags: grammar

The exam is marked out of 50.

Hi,
The sentence above is British. How can I say the sentence above in American English?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, first you'd have to translate it into English.

Comment: I'd say "the perfect score on the exam is 50" or "the number of possible points on the exam is 50."

Comment: Regarding the OP's phrasing, it seems to be more common than one might think. [A Google search](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22marked+out+of%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) has a fair number of results using this phrasing to refer to grading. [This N-gram](goo.gl/KZLrh6) is interesting, but I took a precursory glance at [the book results](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22marked+out+of%22), and some used other senses of "mark." [This forum discussion](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/score-grade-or-mark.473469/) also mentions it in context of British English.

Comment: Apparently shortened links don't work, so [This N-gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=marked+out+of%2Cgraded+out+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmarked%20out%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgraded%20out%20of%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmarked%20out%20of%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cgraded%20out%20of%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: As a British person I can confirm that, formally correct or not, this phrase is widely used.

Answer (score 2):

I’m American, and I find the OP statement to be comprehensible,
but I would say it as

> The exam is graded [or *scored* ] on a scale of 0 to 50.

or

> The exam is graded [or *scored* ] with a maximum grade [or *score* ] of 50.

and I believe that those would be widely understood in the U.S.

If the minimum grade/score is not 0 (or even if it is 0),
you could draw some ideas from a Google search for “[sat score](https://www.google.com/search?site=&source=hp&q=sat+score&oq=sat+score&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l4.3140.6097.0.6330.9.9.0.0.0.0.309.1287.0j5j1j1.7.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..2.7.1285...0i131k1.DxeKbbt1lb0)”;
for example,

> [Method Test Prep](https://info.methodtestprep.com/blog/bid/85068/What-is-a-Good-SAT-score-or-ACT-Score):
>
>   Each of these sections is scored on a scale of 200 to 800 …
>
> [U.S. News & World Report](https://www.usnews.com/education/best-colleges/articles/2017-07-25/understand-whats-a-good-sat-score-for-college-admissions):
>
>   The SAT,
>     an admissions exam many colleges and universities require of applicants,
>     is administered by the College Board
>     and scores students on a scale of 200 to 800 for various sections.
>
> [College Confidential](http://talk.collegeconfidential.com/sat-act-tests-test-preparation/2204-origin-of-the-200-800-scale.html):
>
>   The original SAT test from 1926 (given just to a test group)
>     was actually done on a 200 to 800 scale …
>   ︙
>   … he went to designating the average score as 500
>     with a scale from 200 to 800.